# Best way to handle concurrent access to individual 2D array cells

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, multidimensional-array, concurrency, computer-science

Suppose I have a 2D array representing a terrain with roads. Next, suppose I dispatch n agents on such an environment. Each agent can walk on the road and mark it with its own ID. If an agent sees a road that's been marked with another agent's ID it *shouldn't* continue the search because it would be a waste of time (as another agent has been searching through that road).

I thought about creating a 2D array of mutex locks, each corresponding to a field on a road in the terrain array but that seems like a waste of resources, also setting/unsetting a new mutex lock on each path traversal action seems to be computationally expensive.
How creating the mutex locks more sparsely? As in, creating mutex "checkpoints" on roads? That seems like a compromise between an agent wandering unnecessarily and constant locking/unlocking.

I also thought about ignoring the race condition and hoping that the agent gets another chance to see that some other agent has been traveling through that road.

How should I approach this properly? Is there another, proper way that doesn't involve a lot of mutex locks/semaphores etc?
I'm new to concurrent programming and I feel like my solutions are bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, you could use an `AtomicInteger` for each cell to hold the Agent ID (and initialise the value to say `-1`). Every agent  can then use the `compareAndSet(-1, my-agent-id)` to set its ID on the cell if it hasn't been taken yet.

This would guarantee that an agent stops the first time it encounters a "taken" cell, and is also considered an efficient way to code for such scenarios (as you will be using CAS vs using locks)